# Conversion from std::tuple<T, U> to std::pair<T, U>

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std-pair, stdtuple

Both GCC and Clang (or rather libstdc++ and libc++ respectively) agree that

```
std::is_convertible<std::pair<int, int>, std::tuple<int, int>>::value
```

is `true`, which one should expect since `std::tuple<T, U>` has a non-explicit constructor taking a `pair`.

Going in the other direction however, from a `tuple` to a `pair`, the implementations disagree:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<std::tuple<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>>::value,
              "Cannot convert from tuple to pair");
```

fails with GCC but passes with Clang. I notice that `std::pair` has no constructor taking a `tuple`.

Questions:

- According to the letter of the law, should the latter implicit conversion be allowed, or not? i.e. which implementation is correct here?
- When calling `std::pair<int, int> p = std::make_tuple(3, 4);` under Clang, which `std::pair` constructor is being called?